# I need to test iOS app of 3.5 inch using 4 inch device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I need to test iOS app developed for 3.5 inch version using 4 inch device. I know testing in simulator is a option but few features can only be tested with device. Please any one can any share the solution if known, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try remove splash screen for 4 inch, so you will see your app in 4 inch device with top and bottom black frames.

Comment: I agree, but I don't have splash screen added in the app.

Comment: Remove Launch screen interface file base name from Info.plist, and add new launch image in your Images.xcassets, then you should see the next warning:  Missing "Default-568h@2x.png" launch image

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. The app should run as-is on a 4-inch iPhone.

If you need to ensure that only the 3.5-inch layout is used, make sure there is no `Default-568h@2x.png` image in your application bundle.

Comment: I don't have Default-568h@2x.png in my app, but still it launches perfect in 4 inch device which I want to force it to launch as 3.5 inch app.

Comment: @Kumaran Because you are using asset catalog for app icon and launch images. Remove them and it will appear in 3.5 inch.

Answer (score 1):

You can check via Ipad for sure